# Receive comments as input from user

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using Node.js and [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/) for a small Google Action.

I am trying to receive all of the input from the user after asking them if they want to leave a comment, if the user wants to leave a comment all the things that the user says must be stored in my database.

The problem is that after asking if they want to leave a message my next input is detected as a Fallback Intent.

I have tried to make a custom Event, but I couldn't make it work.

Any suggestions on how to receive the comment and don't fall into the Fallback Intent?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - you can't. But... there are ways that you can setup additional Fallback Intents that are only triggered when you are expecting free-form comments. I'm not sure what you were trying to do with Events, but that is almost certainly not the correct way either - Events aren't for user conversation input, but for other triggering things (GUI triggers, no-input events, etc).

A Fallback Intent is triggered whenever there is input that doesn't match one of the other Intents. Since you want your response to be free-form, by default, it can't match anything else. There is no way to create a normal Intent that would match.

You can, however, have more than one Fallback Intent that are distinguished based on the [context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts).

This way, when you ask the user to provide a comment, you can set a "comment" context and have a Fallback Intent that has "comment" as the Input Context. To create a Fallback Intent this way, select the three-dot menu icon

[image]

And then "Create Fallback Intent"

[image]

Enter a name for the Fallback Intent, add "comment" (or whatever context you choose) as the Input Context, and change the lifespan to 0 in the Output Context (so the context is cleared after the user is done). Don't forget to turn Fulfillment on.

[image]

You can then get the full text of what the user said in your webhook and save this to the database.

One warning, however - the Assistant doesn't generally expect users to talk for very long, so it may cut their comments off or if they pause, even briefly.